# Force an angular 6 component to reload

Tags: angular

Is there any way of forcing an angular component to reload? What I mean by this is, I want everything in my actual component to die, and load again from zero, with it's constructor, `ngOnInit()` and everything.

The I want to do this because I have an app that fetches a lot of data using promises. The data that is fetched depends on some parameters that are controlled by the user within the app.

When these parameters change, the app fetches data again. The problem is: if the last promises haven't ended by the time the parameters are changed, new data is starting to get fetched, but the old promises are still waiting to finish. Plus when they complete, they display wrong information for a couple of seconds. Also, if the new promises finish sooner than the old promises, the app displays the correct information for a few seconds until the old promises end, and then displays wrong information until the parameters are changed again.

Comment: First of all why u're using promises, RxJs's observable is much better. For ur pb please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Reloading the component is not the appropriate fix for the problem. Just learn how to use observables, which have everything to deal with such problems (or hack something with promises, but you'd better use observables, since they're precisely designed to make such things easier). For example:

```
userInput.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(input => this.someService.getData(input))
).subscribe(data => this.displayData(data));
```

Explanation: every time the user input changes, you call the service to get the data, and then display it. If the user input changes and you still haven't got the data, the subscription to the previous data observable is automatically cancelled, and a new subscription to the new data observable is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with routing. Inside ngOnInit()  of a componenet you could redirect to a component that you want to reload.

Comment: And if that component is not linked to a router's path ?